How to change the value of a FluentUI slider in a Jest unit test?
I am writing a Jest unit test and I would like to change the value of a FluentUI slider. Here is the control:
          <Controller
            name="zodApplesQuantity"
            aria-describedby="applesQuantityTooltip"
            control={control}
            render={({ field }) =>
              <Slider {...field}
                min={1}
                max={5}
                defaultValue={applesQuantity}
                showValue
                onChanged={onChangeApplesQuantity}
                data-testid="applesQuantitySlider" 
              />
            }
          />

So since I defined a data-testid, I tried to get the control like that:
const applesQuantitySlider: HTMLElement = await screen.findByTestId("applesQuantitySlider");
fireEvent.change(applesQuantitySlider, { target: { value: 5 } });
   

I'm getting the following error message:
Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="applesQuantitySlider"]

So I tried to use a different approach. Like getting the control by role name, like that:
const applesQuantitySlider: HTMLElement = await screen.findByRole("slider");
fireEvent.change(applesQuantitySlider, { target: { value: 5 } });

Now I have the following error message:
The given element does not have a value setter

Now it seems like I can find the control, but I can't change its value.
So now my question is, what approach should I use to change the value of a FluentUI slider control?
Thanks!
